# Detecting Tap on UICollectionView inside an UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am working with the `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`. I am done with adding the contents and I am able to see the `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`.

But now I don't know how to check which `cell` of `UICollectionView` is tapped inside the which row of `UITableView`.

So if anybody knows how to recognize it pls help.

Thanks in advance.

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 15;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CellForCollectionView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellForCollectionView"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CellForCollectionView alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellForCollectionView"];
    }

    cell.categoryCollectionView.delegate = self;
    cell.categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self;

    [cell.categoryCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionCellForCategory" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCellForCategory"];
    cell.lblCategoryName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Category %d",indexPath.row];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}






#pragma mark
#pragma mark - UIcollectionViewDelegate and UIcollectionViewDatasource
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 15;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CollectionCellForCategory *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCellForCategory" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imagCategory.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
    cell.imagCategory.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    return cell;
}


-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section);
}
```

Comment: Did select not working for collection view?

Comment: yes did select is working but using this how can I recognize the row number of UITableView.

Comment: can you give me the idea of your UI.

Comment: how u loaded the tableview show ur code we can help u

Comment: You can subclass UICollectionView and and a variable to track the indexPath of the tableViewCell and set the variable in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method of UITableViewDatasource.

Comment: Can you post the code for "CellForCollectionView" class?

Comment: thanks @firstinq the way you suggested worked for me.

Comment: Glad it helped. Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can subclass UICollectionView and add a variable to track the indexPath of the tableViewCell
2. In your tableViewCell change the collectionView type to your custom collectionView
3. Set the variable in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method of UITableViewDatasource

Custom collectionView:

```
@interface IndexedCollectionView : UICollectionView
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath* parentIndexpath;
@end
```

Your custom tableViewCell (approx.)

```
@interface CellForCollectionView : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet IndexedCollectionView* categoryCollectionView;
@end
```

UITableViewDataSource method implementation:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CellForCollectionView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellForCollectionView"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CellForCollectionView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellForCollectionView"];
    }

    cell.categoryCollectionView.delegate = self;
    cell.categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self;

    [cell.categoryCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionCellForCategory" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCellForCategory"];
     cell.lblCategoryName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Category %d",indexPath.row];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.categoryCollectionView.parentIndexpath = indexPath;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: hey I have one small doubt pls
Actually due to the cell reusability it is not updating the "parentIndexpath" of other cell's in UITableView so can you please suggest me the solution for this if you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit off-topic, but in case someone has the same problem as myself having collection view cells touch inside tableview work and reached this question looking for an answer :

It **does** work with all the default settings. So, make sure you don't have another touch gesture in your view controller (such as a tap gesture like me) blocking the touch from reaching the collection view cell.

If you have such a gesture recognizer, and you want to keep it, you need to set its "cancelTouchesInView" property to false. And that's all. You don't need to implement the IUGestureRecognizerDelegate functions to have it work (although that may be different if you have multiple gesture recognizer and not just one).

Answer (score -1):

It's simple. Add tag to each cell of `UITableView` in "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`:" method i.e

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row
```

same goes for the CollectionViewCell inside the UICollectionView

Let say you have a tableView with 2 rows and which is having 2 collectionViews respectively.

row1 of UITableView will have tag `0` and other one will have tag `1`.

Now when the user clicks on the collectionViewCell inside the collectionView which is inside a UITableViewCell

Now, if you click the first collectionViewCell of the collectionView inside the first UITableViewCell

You will get the cell tag as 0 and as you already know that `self.tag` i.e is the tableViewCell is `0`

Now, if you click the first collectionViewCell of the collectionView inside the 2nd UITableViewCell

You will get the cell tag as 0 and as you already know that `self.tag` i.e is the tableViewCell is `1`

I think this was what you needed.Do let me know if it's clear to you.. Thanks :)